# VB.Net: How to use an Object data source in report (.rdlc)

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc, objectdatasource

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514965/rdlc-reporting-bound-to-object-data-source-in-three-layer-application) but I'm having some problems with the actual implementation.

I've got a report (.rdlc) in the business layer of a 3-tier app.

I've got an object in the BL (`EmployeeManager`) which has a `GetEmployees(Expression as Expression(Of Func(Of Employee, Boolean))) As IQueryable(Of Employee)` method.

As I didn't want to try and pass a lambda in directly (at least not until I've got something working), I've created a `ReportData` class in the BL which wraps the `GetEmployees()` call and exposes the results as an IEnumerable(Of Employee) - which should be very simple. It doesn't even have parameters at the moment.

Ok... So In my report, I've tried to add a new Data Source. I've picked a type of `Object` and located the `ReportData` class mentioned above. The wizard completes and adds a DataSources folder to the project inside which is some XML defining a `<GenericObjectDataSource>` and pointing at the `Report` class.

`ReportData` also appears in the Data Sources pane - It has a `>` next to it but when I expand it, it has no children.

What I don't know how to do is USE the data source - It doesn't seem to expose any methods/members (I haven't even specified that it should call `GetEmployees()` yet!) and I certainly can't see an `IEnumerable(Of Employee)` anywhere.

When I try to add a table to the report and it prompts me to select a Dataset, the ReportData Datasource is not shown in the Data source drop-down.

What am I missing? Can someone please point me in the right direction?

My simple ReportData object:

```vb
Namespace Reports
    Public Class ReportData

        Private Property EmployeeManager As Interfaces.IEmployeeManager

        Public Sub New()
            ''This sub is here in case it's an instantiation problem - I intend to use dependency injection when I've got this working properly.
            Me.EmployeeManager = New EmployeeManager
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(ByVal EmployeeManager As Interfaces.IEmployeeManager)
            Me.EmployeeManager = EmployeeManager
        End Sub

        Public Function GetEmployees() As IEnumerable(Of Employee)
            Return EmployeeManager.GetEmployees()
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I've also found [this](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/objectdatasources/index.html) which seems to indicate I'm following the correct steps but the properties don't appear as expected

> The public properties of the class now appear in the Data Sources window, where they can be dragged and dropped into the report.

This doesn't happen - the properties never appear

**EDIT**: As pointed out by Alex, I need to use **properties** not just any methods. Please see Alex Esselfie's answer below for clarification. This still hasn't solved my problem but has got me a step closer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description and accompanying code, there are no properties in the `ReportData` class. If I reckon well, that class is supposed to be generating the `IEnumerable` you want to display on the report.

If that's the case, you'll have to select the **`Employee`** class as the DataSource in the wizard. This will allow you to display the data on your report.

I'll work on a quick project and add it to this answer in a moment.

---

**Edit 1**

### How to Bind a Class to a Report

**Visual Studio 2008**

1. Open the report in **Design View**.
2. Select from the menu bar `Data` > `Show Data Sources`
3. Click **Add New Data Source** on the Data Sources window.
4. Select **Object** and click *Next*.
5. Browse the solution tree and select the class you want to bind to.
   In your case, you bind to the ***Employee*** class.
6. Click *Next* and then *Finish*.

**Visual Studio 2010**

1. Open the report in **Design View**.
2. Select from the menu bar `View` > `Report Data`
3. Click `New` > `Dataset...` on the Data Sources window.
4. Enter a name for the dataset (e.g. Employee)
5. Create a *New Data source* or select an existing data source.

   **Creating a New Data source**

   - Select **Object** and click *Next*.
   - Browse the solution tree and select the class(es) you want to bind to.
   - Click *Finish*.

After binding a class to the report, go ahead and design your report as usual.

---

**Edit 2**

I uploaded a sample project for you. Here's the [link](http://www29.zippyshare.com/v/65878637/file.html).
If you need further clarification, please notify me so I give you a step by step procedure on how to replicate the project.

Comment: Thank you - do you mean that it actually has to be a property not a function? I'd appreciate the sample project but I'll test that as well...

Comment: Ok, changing it to a property has got me further - I can now see a child element (GetEmployees()) on the Data source in the Data sources pane - but it's still not listed when I add a table and it asks me for a data set - Do I need to do something to use a data source as a data set?

Comment: It is a class that you bind a report to. When a class is bound to a report, it's properties become possible fields for display on that report. Therefore you'll have to bind the report to the return value (`Employee` in this case).

Comment: I just finished the sample project. Do you want me to upload the entire project or should I just edit my answer to display the meat of the project.

Comment: Hi Alex, can you clarify how I would bind the report? I can't see anything in the properties pane which seems to apply...

Comment: Basiclife, which version of VS are you using? 2008/2010?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. My internet connection got disconnected. I updated the answer to show how to bind a class to the report.

Comment: Hi Alex, not a problem... If I do "Show Data Sources", I get a data sources window with a  very small tree (Reports -> ReportData -> GetEmployees). There is no "New" option. Buttons I have are: Add new data source (not set). Refresh. Greyed out are: Edit Dataset with designer and configure data source with wizard. These remain greyed out no matter which node is selected. On the VS Data menu, I have Add new Data Source again but no mention of set...

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot here: http://img25.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=65460_UI_122_6lo.jpg

Comment: After seeing your screenshot I think it's best I upload the sample project. Pardon my tardiness. I've been having a poor internet connection today.

Comment: Basiclife, I'm sorry I made a slight mistake in the procedure for adding a data source in VS2010. Please see the updated answer for the corrected version.

Comment: +1 Alex - Thank you so much for your help on this. You've been very helpful and I really appreciate the step-by-step above. I've now managed to get data into my report. I've still got questions but you've answered this one - I'll open some new ones up over the next day or so.

Comment: No problem. I had to learn MS Reports last month on my own with no assistance whatsoever so as much as possible, I try not to let anyone go through that experience. Knowledge is meant to be shared after all.

Comment: Thanks. In case you're interested, follow-up Q is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726658/using-microsoft-reports-rdlc-in-a-3-tier-app

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I had to add a Data Source (Object Type) to my presentation layer that pointed to my Object in the Business layer (collection with property class). I created the report (.rdlc) in the presentation layer and pointed it to the Data Source and everthing working fine. This was the only way I found to expose the field properties to the report. At runtime I bind the report datasource to the collection. I like to design a "flat" collection in the business layer, process the data and send it to the rdlc keeping the report as "dumb" as possible.

Comment: I couldn't agree more - I'd love to offload some of the complex stuff to the report (as is logical) but it seems that trying for anything more than a dumb dataset is a recipe for disaster - definitely an area of the MS stack that needs an overhaul. You should see the overhead when I ask the reporting engine to group/sort as opposed to a simple Linq query...