# How to bind Report Viewer with a Dictionary<string,int> as the data source?

Tags: c#, data-binding, reportviewer

I've got a list of name-value pairs that I'm wanting to put in a nice report format.  Is it possible to use this as a data source for a ReportViewer object?  This is in WinForms and ASP.

Comment: Is the `ReportViewer` a WPF control? If so, I would imagine you could achieve what you want in the same way you would through standard item binding. If not, maybe this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837625/using-ms-reportviewer-in-wpf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to convert the Dictionary to a DataTable and use that as the DataSource.

```
var table = new DataTable();
var kvps = dictionary.ToArray();
table.Columns.AddRange(kvps.Select(kvp => new DataColumn(kvp.Name)).ToArray());
table.LoadDataRow(kvps.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToArray(), true);
bindingSource.DataSource = table;
```

Voilà

Comment: how do you refer to a well named key (column/row) of the data source inside the rdlc design mode ? I have tried `=Fields("somekey")!FirstName.Value` and `=Fields!FirstName.Value("somekey")` whithout success

Comment: @Bellash sorry, it's been too long ago and I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to create a class to encapsulate the items you'd like to display in the report. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717517/vb-net-how-to-use-an-object-data-source-in-report-rdlc/3717795#3717795) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717517) for how to bind a class to a report.

The code's in VB.NET but you'll be able to follow it quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's not going to naturally bind in the ReportViewer.  Just put them in a list of custom objects with the properties you want to bind to.  It wouldn't be a lot of overhead (like a List.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not suited as data source for lists. They are optimized for retrieving values for given keys. Nevertheless, you can retrieve the keys, the values and key/value pairs from the dictionary as follows:

```
var keys = dict.Keys;
var values = dict.Values;
var keyValuePairs = dict.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in keyValuePairs) {
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```