# RDLC: How to refer to a row when using Dictionary<string,TValue> as datasource?

Tags: c#, dictionary, reporting, rdlc, strongly-typed-dataset

Here is how I insert data in the dictionary

```
  Dictionary<string, Person> dict=new Dictionary();
  dict.Add("dev",new Person("John","Skeet"))
  dict.Add("code",new Person("Theodor","Bellash"))
  dict.Add("chief",new Person("John","Skeet"))
```

I have a data source typed as `Dictionary<string,Person>` and I wonder how can I refer to `dict["chief"]` in the RDLC design mode?

I have tried `=Fields("chief")!FirstName.Value` and `=Fields!FirstName.Value("chief")` whithout success.

Comment: pls can you post picture of report data toolbox so i can take a look at the data dictionary?

Answer (score -1):

Add a `Key` property in your `Person` object so that your row is set as follows

```
new Person("dev","John","Skeet"))
```

and then use the collection of these objects as your report data source or [convert your dictionary into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535877/how-to-bind-report-viewer-with-a-dictionarystring-int-as-the-data-source#answer-8538087).